# Activerecord get multiple most recent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following, simplified table:

```
| id | order_id | created_at |  
| 1  |  1       | 2011-07-11 |  
| 2  |  1       | 2011-07-12 |  
| 3  |  2       | 2011-07-13 |  
| 4  |  2       | 2011-07-14 |
```

Now i'm trying to get all records for a list of orders, but only the latest one for each order_id

```
EdpuOrder.find(:all, :conditions => "edpu_orders.order_id IN (#{ids})", :order => "edpu_orders.created_at")
```

The ids variable is generated by a subquery, let's say it's "1, 2" for now. The statement above should return the records 2 and 4. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Ruby / Rails, updated the tags list...

Comment: Which elements is it returning?

Comment: The statement above gives me all records in the list

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953512/rails-3-1-with-postgresql-group-by-must-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function/6953704#6953704

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to put the ids in an array.

```
ids = [1, 2]
EdpuOrder.where(:order_id => ids).order(:created_at)
```

By the way this will only work for Rails 3 and above.

Comment: That would give me all four records, ordered by date while i need only need records 2 and 4...

Answer (score 0):

Try this scope (i replace `your_table` with proper  table name):

```
named_scope :top_orders, :from=>"(select * from your_table order by created_at desc) as tmp", :group => "order_id"
```

Now `YourModel.top_orders` should do the thing

Answer (score 0):

```
EdpuOrder.where("(edpu_orders.order_id, edpu_orders.id) IN 
         (SELECT order_id, MAX(id) FROM edpu_orders GROUP BY order_id)").
order("created_at DESC")
```