# Rails fetch row with latest update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have such db table structure:

id |  currency_list_id  |  direction_id  |  value  | updated_at

and i have such data:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 8150 | 09-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 1 | 2 | 8250 | 09-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 2 | 1 | 8150 | 06-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 2 | 2 | 8150 | 06-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 1 | 1 | 8150 | 09-08-2010 15:00:00
1 | 1 | 2 | 8250 | 09-08-2010 15:00:00
```

so currency in exchanger is setted almost everyday, and could be setted more than one time in a day.... but also one could be setted some days ago... And i must to fetch all actual data..

How in rails (ruby) i could fetch only last actual data?

In my example result will be:

```
1 | 2 | 1 | 8150 | 06-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 2 | 2 | 8150 | 06-08-2010 01:00:00
1 | 1 | 1 | 8150 | 09-08-2010 15:00:00
1 | 1 | 2 | 8250 | 09-08-2010 15:00:00
```

how to do this?

i try so:

```
@currencies = CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => id}, :order => :updated_at)
```

but then i will fetch all data for some currency_list_id with ordering, but how to fetch only last 2 values?   How to fetch last 2 ordered rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@currencies = CurrencyValue.find(:all, :conditions => {:currency_list_id => id, :order => :updated_at}).last(2)
```

I think :). Can't check this right now.

Comment: hm to strange by me: but i need to do one array of all currency_list_id without putting it in condition... so last 2 for every currency_list_id in db

Comment: Ah, I think you might find group_by useful then :). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302992/rails-activerecord-group-results-into-sub-collections-by-date for a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need by be a `GROUP_BY`. There's another question that explains it here:

[How to get the latest record in each group using GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999522/how-to-get-the-latest-record-in-each-group-using-group-by)