# Mysql to Postgresql Rails PG::GroupingError: ERROR:

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I just deployed my app and had to switch from mysql to postgresql.
Now when executing my query I get following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "search_terms.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "search_terms".* FROM "search_terms" WHERE (search_te...
               ^
: SELECT "search_terms".* FROM "search_terms" WHERE (search_terms.term like '%%') GROUP BY search_terms.game_id):
```

I have a table called `search_terms` with `term:string` and `game_id:integer`. A game can have multiple terms. So I want to group the terms that match by the `game_id`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

In my model `search_term.rb`, I have defined this search function:

```
# Search Terms
  def self.search(query)
    where("search_terms.term like ?", "%#{query}%").group("search_terms.game_id")
  end
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the **Related** questions in the sidebar? Searched for ["\[postgresql\] must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+must+appear+in+the+GROUP+BY+clause+or+be+used+in+an+aggregate+function) perhaps? This problem happens quite often.

Comment: Hi, checked the topics. One has the same question, but didnt get solved.

Comment: I re-coded the search function using `select(:game_id).distinct` and then let it get fetched by `Game.where(id: my_distinct_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to try.

```
 def self.search(query)
    where("search_terms.term like ?", "%#{query}%").group("search_terms.game_id", "search_terms.term")
  end
```

explanation here: [Rails 3.1 with PostgreSQL: GROUP BY must be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953512/rails-3-1-with-postgresql-group-by-must-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function)

Comment: Hi, I tried this and with search_terms.id inside group. It will produce a different a SQL statement and I will receive duplicates on game_id.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM search_terms WHERE (search_terms.term like "%di%" ) GROUP BY search_terms.game_id`

id 2 | game_id 1

id 3 | game_id 2

`SELECT * FROM search_terms WHERE (search_terms.term like "%di%" ) GROUP BY search_terms.game_id, search_terms.id`

id 1 | game_id 1

id 2 | game_id 1

id 3 | game_id 2

`SELECT * FROM search_terms WHERE (search_terms.term like "%di%" ) GROUP BY search_terms.game_id, search_terms.term`

id 2 | game_id 1

id 1 | game_id 1

id 3 | game_id 2